# 3D graphics that fade with distance

Tags: graphics3d, opacity

I'm looking to create a 3D graphic that fades into the background the further away things are. For example (the Right/Center cubes):

[image: 3D cubes]

I figured the way to do this would be to create almost see-through disks, however it seems that turning opacity close to zero doesn't actually make 3D objects see-through.

```
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None],Cylinder[{{-10,10,-10},{0,0,0}},4],Opacity[0.03],
  Table[Cylinder[{{i,-i,i},{0.01+i,-0.01-i,0.01+i}},30],{i,-10,0}]}]
```

[image: See-through disks]

I've looked at perhaps using lighting to do this, but this also changes the shading of the object, which I don't want. Similarly, using ClipPlanes distorts the object appearance. Any suggestions?

Comment: something like `vp = {1.3, -2.4, 2.};
DensityPlot3D[
 Norm[{x, y, z} - vp], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
 BoxStyle -> Thick, Axes -> False, ColorFunction -> (White &), 
 OpacityFunction -> Function[f, .05 Sqrt@f], ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp]]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For starters, we can use [`DensityPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DensityPlot3D.html) + [`OpacityFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OpacityFunction.html) to get cubes with a fog effect:

```
vp = {1.3, -2.4, 2.}; 

DensityPlot3D[
 Norm[{x, y, z} - vp], 
 {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
 BoxStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[5], 
 Axes -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> (White &), 
 OpacityFunction -> Function[f, .075 Sqrt@f], 
 ViewPoint -> vp, 
 SphericalRegion -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can shade by depth in `Graphics3D` [[ref](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics3D.html#1591867625)]:

```
Graphics3D[
  {EdgeForm[None], Cylinder[{{-10, 10, -10}, {0, 0, 0}}, 4]},
  Method -> {"OneLayer" -> {"Depth" -> 1}}
]
```

[image]